# How to detect deviation with pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some data that contains 5 columns and 1000 rows. Now I just picked up 3 random rows:

```
5 5 5 0.1 0.2

4 4 4 4   0.3

4 3 3 3   1
```

How can I detect the deviation in each row? For example in the first row there are two 0s and in the second row there is one 0. I tried using mean but that is not the right solution.

Comment: What do you mean by *deviation*?

Comment: I need to filter out the values with the biggest deviation of the other values in each row

Comment: Try the median, instead of the mean. Although for me still isn't clear what do you mean

Comment: I just edited the code a bit. Now in my case in the first row, i got 2 very low values (0.1 and 0.2). Is there a way to filter these 2 values?

Comment: I guess you want to filter very large numbers to?

Comment: I mean, in the first row, there are 3 values similiar (5) and 2 values lower than that (0.1 and 0.2). I wanna get these lower values filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
n=3
new_df=df.loc[:,~(df.diff(axis=1).abs()>n).any()]
print(new_df)
   col1  col2  col3
0   5.0   5.0   5.0
1   4.0   4.0   4.0
2   4.0   3.0   3.0
```

---

```
new_df=df.loc[:,(df.diff(axis=1).abs()>n).any()]
print(new_df)
   col4  col5
0   0.1   0.2
1   4.0   0.3
2   3.0   1.0
```

**you can select the interval you want.**

---

**Differences**

```
print(df.diff(axis=1).abs())

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   NaN   0.0   0.0   4.9   0.1
1   NaN   0.0   0.0   0.0   3.7
2   NaN   1.0   0.0   0.0   2.0
```